# How to test view and controller logic that relies on the created_at property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm brand new to Ruby on Rails.

I have an application with a simple controller and view that render an HTML page with a list of Active Record objects from my database in least-recently-created (oldest first) order.

I'm attempt to write a test that verifies this sorting behavior by creating two objects with different `created_at` values, then verifying that the generated HTML has the oldest item first (using `assert_select`).

However, when I try to manually alter the `created_at` value on one of my objects (to ensure that my objects don't have the same `created_at` value), the other properties of the object appear to be set to a default value.  For example, this code in my test results in an `Image` object with an `url` property value of `http://www.example.com/image1.png`, as expected:

```
@image1 = Image.create!(url: 'http://www.example.com/image1.png')
```

However, this code results in the `url` property value in the database unexpectedly changing to `MyString`:

```
@image1 = Image.create!(url: 'http://www.example.com/image1.png')
@image1.created_at = '2017-09-25'
@image1.save
```

I'm using ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5.1.1.1 (per my Gemfile).

I have two questions at this point:

1. Why does setting the `created_at` value on my object have the apparent side effect of changing the value of the `url` property to `MyString`? Is changing the `created_at` date just not allowed?
2. What's the proper way to go about arranging data in a test that exercises logic where the `created_at` dates of objects need to have particular values?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you using FactoryGirl?

2) Is an uploader class attached to the Image model?

3) Can you modify the Image object inside the test console?

```
 $ RAILS_ENV=test bin/bundle exec bin/rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `created_at` attribute should be `DateTime` instead of `String`. You mess up the test object when trying to assign a string to the `created_at` attribute. Try the following

```
@image1.created_at = 2.days.from_now
```

or

```
@image1.created_at = 2.days.ago
```